# Keep getting breakpoint error when trying to run iOS application on iphone simulator with xcode 5

Tags: ios, objective-c, debugging, xcode5, breakpoints

I just started creating a new checklist app for the first time.

So far I have added a Table View object and Table View Cell object to the app's UI in main.storyboard.

I then went to my View Controller header file and made sure to change the superclass type to "UITableViewController".

I then went to my View Controller main file and added the following methods:

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return 1;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableview:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath         *)indexPath
{

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ChecklistItem"];

return cell;

}
```

I keep getting a breakpoint error and cannot get the app to run on the iPhone simulator. I have tried starting from scratch and recreating this app 3 times now and have also tried using different simulators, and still nothing is working.

Whenever I try running the app this is the final output in the debug console:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Also, here is a link to a screenshot of what my xcode looks like when I try to run the program and get the breakpoint error: http://oi40.tinypic.com/25im3kn.jpg

I have gotten breakpoint errors many times in the past but usually can fix everything by just going to Debug > Deactivate Breakpoints but that is not working for me right now.

Any help is greatly appreciated thank you.

PS. Also, here is the entire output in the debug console log:

```
2013-12-18 18:25:55.183 Checklists[4910:70b] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView     _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-    2903.23/UITableView.m:6246
2013-12-18 18:25:55.190 Checklists[4910:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception     'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from     tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x017385e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x014bb8b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
2   CoreFoundation                      0x01738448 +[NSException     raise:format:arguments:] + 136
3   Foundation                          0x0109bfee -[NSAssertionHandler     handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 116
4   UIKit                               0x003123d5 __53-[UITableView     _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:]_block_invoke + 426
5   UIKit                               0x0028b3ef +[UIView(Animation)    performWithoutAnimation:] + 82
6   UIKit                               0x0028b438 +[UIView(Animation) _performWithoutAnimation:] + 40
7   UIKit                               0x00312226 -[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:] + 108
8   UIKit                               0x0031863d -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:] + 442
9   UIKit                               0x003186f3 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:] + 69
10  UIKit                               0x002fc774 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 2378
11  UIKit                               0x0030fe95 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 213
12  UIKit                               0x00294267 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate)    layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 355
13  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x014cd81f -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70
14  QuartzCore                          0x03b462ea -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 148
15  QuartzCore                          0x03b3a0d4 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 380
16  QuartzCore                          0x03b46235 -[CALayer layoutIfNeeded] + 160
17  UIKit                               0x0034f613 -[UIViewController window:setupWithInterfaceOrientation:] + 304
18  UIKit                               0x0026e177 -[UIWindow _setRotatableClient:toOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:isRotating:] + 5212
19  UIKit                               0x0026cd16 -[UIWindow _setRotatableClient:toOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:] + 82
20  UIKit                               0x0026cbe8 -[UIWindow _setRotatableViewOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:] + 117
21  UIKit                               0x0026cc70 -[UIWindow _setRotatableViewOrientation:duration:force:] + 67
22  UIKit                               0x0026bd0a __57-[UIWindow _updateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:force:]_block_invoke + 120
23  UIKit                               0x0026bc6c -[UIWindow _updateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:force:] + 400
24  UIKit                               0x0026c9c3 -[UIWindow setAutorotates:forceUpdateInterfaceOrientation:] + 870
25  UIKit                               0x0026ffb6 -[UIWindow setDelegate:] + 449
26  UIKit                               0x00341737 -[UIViewController _tryBecomeRootViewControllerInWindow:] + 180
27  UIKit                               0x00265c1c -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 609
28  UIKit                               0x00265d97 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 312
29  UIKit                               0x0026602d -[UIWindow _orderFrontWithoutMakingKey] + 49
30  UIKit                               0x0027089a -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 65
31  UIKit                               0x00223cd0 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1851
32  UIKit                               0x002283a8 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 824
33  UIKit                               0x0023c87c -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3447
34  UIKit                               0x0023cde9 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 85
35  UIKit                               0x0022a025 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 736
36  GraphicsServices                    0x036df2f6 _PurpleEventCallback + 776
37  GraphicsServices                    0x036dee01 PurpleEventCallback + 46
38  CoreFoundation                      0x016b3d65 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53
39  CoreFoundation                      0x016b3a9b __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 523
40  CoreFoundation                      0x016de77c __CFRunLoopRun + 2156
41  CoreFoundation                      0x016ddac3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
42  CoreFoundation                      0x016dd8db CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
43  UIKit                               0x00227add -[UIApplication _run] + 840
44  UIKit                               0x00229d3b UIApplicationMain + 1225
45  Checklists                          0x00001b7d main + 141
46  libdyld.dylib                       0x01d7670d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

PPS. After making your change, my view controller main file now looks like this:

```
#import "ChecklistsViewController.h"

@interface ChecklistsViewController ()

@end

@implementation ChecklistsViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return 1;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableview:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath
{

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ChecklistItem"]; if(!cell) { cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault     reuseIdentifier:@"ChecklistItem"]; }

return cell;
}


@end
```

I still get an error and now this is what the console log is showing:

```
2013-12-18 18:42:14.609 Checklists[5014:70b] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView    _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-    2903.23/UITableView.m:6246
2013-12-18 18:42:14.614 Checklists[5014:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from     tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x017395e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x014bc8b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
2   CoreFoundation                      0x01739448 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 136
3   Foundation                          0x0109cfee -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 116
4   UIKit                               0x003133d5 __53-[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:]_block_invoke + 426
5   UIKit                               0x0028c3ef +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:] + 82
6   UIKit                               0x0028c438 +[UIView(Animation) _performWithoutAnimation:] + 40
7   UIKit                               0x00313226 -[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:] + 108
8   UIKit                               0x0031963d -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:] + 442
9   UIKit                               0x003196f3 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:] + 69
10  UIKit                               0x002fd774 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 2378
11  UIKit                               0x00310e95 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 213
12  UIKit                               0x00295267 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 355
13  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x014ce81f -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70
14  QuartzCore                          0x03b472ea -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 148
15  QuartzCore                          0x03b3b0d4 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 380
16  QuartzCore                          0x03b47235 -[CALayer layoutIfNeeded] + 160
17  UIKit                               0x00350613 -[UIViewController window:setupWithInterfaceOrientation:] + 304
18  UIKit                               0x0026f177 -[UIWindow _setRotatableClient:toOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:isRotating:] + 5212
19  UIKit                               0x0026dd16 -[UIWindow _setRotatableClient:toOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:] + 82
20  UIKit                               0x0026dbe8 -[UIWindow _setRotatableViewOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:] + 117
21  UIKit                               0x0026dc70 -[UIWindow _setRotatableViewOrientation:duration:force:] + 67
22  UIKit                               0x0026cd0a __57-[UIWindow _updateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:force:]_block_invoke + 120
23  UIKit                               0x0026cc6c -[UIWindow _updateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:force:] + 400
24  UIKit                               0x0026d9c3 -[UIWindow setAutorotates:forceUpdateInterfaceOrientation:] + 870
25  UIKit                               0x00270fb6 -[UIWindow setDelegate:] + 449
26  UIKit                               0x00342737 -[UIViewController _tryBecomeRootViewControllerInWindow:] + 180
27  UIKit                               0x00266c1c -[UIWindow    addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 609
28  UIKit                               0x00266d97 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] +     312
29  UIKit                               0x0026702d -[UIWindow _orderFrontWithoutMakingKey] + 49
30  UIKit                               0x0027189a -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 65
31  UIKit                               0x00224cd0 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1851
32  UIKit                               0x002293a8 -[UIApplication    _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 824
33  UIKit                               0x0023d87c -[UIApplication     handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3447
34  UIKit                               0x0023dde9 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 85
35  UIKit                               0x0022b025 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 736
36  GraphicsServices                    0x036e02f6 _PurpleEventCallback + 776
37  GraphicsServices                    0x036dfe01 PurpleEventCallback + 46
38  CoreFoundation                      0x016b4d65     __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53
39  CoreFoundation                      0x016b4a9b __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 523
40  CoreFoundation                      0x016df77c __CFRunLoopRun + 2156
41  CoreFoundation                      0x016deac3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
42  CoreFoundation                      0x016de8db CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
43  UIKit                               0x00228add -[UIApplication _run] + 840
44  UIKit                               0x0022ad3b UIApplicationMain + 1225
45  Checklists                          0x00002aed main + 141
46  libdyld.dylib                       0x01d7770d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: If you share the logs that appear before "terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException" would be great!

Comment: Nvinhas I just updated my original question with the entire log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the code `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` is not returning a cell.

1. Check if your cell in the XIB as the Reuse Identifier set to `"ChecklistItem"`
2. If the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` returns `nil` create a new cell.

   ```
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ChecklistItem"]; 
   if(!cell) {
       cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"ChecklistItem"];
   }
   ```

That should fix your problem.

Comment: I tried adding your solution and I am still getting an error. I ahve updated my original question with the code change you suggested and what the console log is now showing me.

Comment: That's weird, because the log says that the method cellForRowAtIndexPath: is returning a nil cell. Can you put a breakpoint in the return of that method and see if it is returning nil or not?
If the cell is equal to nil it will enter in that if and will create a new one, so it cannot return nil.

Comment: I'm not familar with using breakpoints. I just did q quick google search and tried adding this: asm("trap") and i added it before the "return cell;" statement. Should I be using a different breakpoint statement? Should I be adding the breakpoint statement somewhere else in the code?

Comment: Did you set the delegate and the datasource of the table correctly?

I recommend you to read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) of the UITableView.

Comment: On the left of the line of code you can put a breakpoint. It is a blue arrow. That means that in the runtime when the code reaches that line it will stop and will show you information about the variables.

Then you can see the value of the cell and check if it is nil or not.

Hope it helps.

Comment: To better understand breakpoints see this tutorial. [link](http://codewithchris.com/xcode-tutorial/)

Comment: I am going to go take a tutorial on breakpoints and take it from there. I really appreciate all of your help though. Thank you.

Comment: Hi again. Do I want to put the breakpoint next to the "return cell;" statement or next to the code that you provided to me earlier?

Comment: If you put in the return cell you will see if the var `cell` is `nil` or not. If it is `nil` then you can put a breakpoint inside the if I provided to make sure it is enter inside of it.

Comment: I put it next to the return cell statement. Am I correct in looking to see if cell is nil or not in the debug console output? I did a search for "cell" and it pops up 8 times and only once all by itself. Nowhere does it say "cell = nil" and I search for "nil" and nil does not come up at all in the console.

Comment: In the [screenshot](http://d.pr/i/XqwZ) are two columns. When you are stopped in a breakpoint your vars are displayed in the left column. There you can find your `cell` variable and see if it is `nil`or not.